# Interrupt service routines in Java

Tags: java, eclipse, assembly

The question may sound a bit weird. I want to have a complete control over my keyboard. In assembly language it is possible by changing the address of the ISR running in the keyboard port. Is it possible in Java? How can I find my keyboard port number and how can I redirect the request coming in the keyboard port to my ISR?

Comment: DOS was the last OS in common use where user code could chain ISRs and touch x86 i/o ports.  You're running Eclipse over DOS?

Comment: no.I am using windows 7 on a 64 bit platform

Comment: which file r u talking about

Comment: No you can't do this in Java. Windows won't let you anywhere near the keyboard port unless you write a special device driver.

Answer (score 1):

**There is absolutely no way to do what you are asking.**

While writing an ISR in Java would be exceptionally difficult, the problem doesn't specifically have anything to do with your programming language choice. Rather, it has to do with user-mode / kernel-mode privilege separation.

On modern OSes, the Interrupt Service Routines are completely handled in the kernel, which is protected from userspace (read: "you") by hardware. To interact with the hardware at this level while booted into Windows, you're going to need to write a kernel-mode device driver. Even that may not be enough for hardware like a keyboard, which Windows wants to have exclusive control over.

If you want to play with hardware at this level, your best bet would be to actually boot your system (or a Virtual Machine) to DOS (not DOSBox, not a command prompt, but actual DOS), and brush up on your 16-bit real-mode Intel assembly, and [BIOS calls](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_interrupt_call).

If you're trying to write a keylogger, or otherwise mess around with they keyboard's interaction with your running applications, you can look into the [Win32 hooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644959.aspx).

Comment: I might sound stupid but is 16 bit mode programing possible in a 64 bit machine.Is dos available for 64 bit machines

Comment: Yes. All x86 processors still power-on in the same 16-bit "real mode" that the original [8086](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_8086) did.

Comment: I used to write my asm programs in masm32 editor.But that is not working in my 64 bit m/c.To be more specific the link563.exe is not getting installed. Where would i write my programs?any good editor